# Python package not found, no module named "coroapi"

Tags: python, api, pip, pypi

I created a package and uploaded the package to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/coroapi/), installed it with `PIP` and when I try to test and `import` it, it can't find the my package
called `coroapi`, and it's its `GitHub` - [coronavirus-api](https://github.com/r0eilevi/coronavirus-api)

Who can try to download and use because maybe I made a mistake there, because it's only a second time that I create a package, or just check it out please, because I'm stuck on it, and I want to finally release it.

**Example**

```
import coroapi

instance = coroapi.Corona()
usa_infected_people = instance.get_country_infected('usa', text=False)
print(usa_infected_people)

>> No module named "coroapi"
```

**Pip output:**

```
> pip3 install coroapi
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: coroapi in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from coroapi) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from coroapi) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->coroapi) (2.0)
```

Comment: A couple question: Are you installing the package in a virtualenv and do you have multiple version of python on your computer?

Comment: @YacineMahdid I'm using Ubuntu so I have python2 and python3 installed, I'm using the terminal to install it and I'm using VS-CODE

Comment: Okay great, it might be that you are running the code in two different version of python. Could you check what version of python is used when your example?

Comment: @YacineMahdid I running my code always with writing `python3 my_file.py`, also, as you can see, I always running `pip3 install package`.

Comment: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coroapi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coroapi"

Comment: @Bar Yes, but you might have slightly different version of python 3 installed which would make the installation your pip3 install not visible to your code. Use sys.version to double check that you are in fact running python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.version

Comment: @YacineMahdid `3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34)`

Comment: @bug_spray Oh, can you please check it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your package is not installing all of the files in your project. If you run `pip3 show -f coroapi`, you'll see that it is showing only a directory called `coroapi-1.1.dist-info`, not one for `coroapi`.

You can also see this on your [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/coroapi/#files) page. If you download your tar.gz file, you'll notice it doesn't include your `coroapi` folder at all:

[image: Missing files]

I cloned your Github repo and ran `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, and it created a `dist` directory with a tar.gz file including everything correctly. So maybe you just published an old version of your package to PyPi. Try rebuilding and uploading again. Follow [this page](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/) as a guide.